# When focus is in input text, how to make tab key to move focus to options drop-down?

Tags: html, input

When focus is in input text, how to make tab key to move focus to options drop-down?
In the example below, type "f", you have two options then press tab, it jumps to button after. How to make this that the focus jumps into options drop-down.

I know up / down keys do that.
I added tabindex, as I got suggestion but without success.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" list="browsers" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Search ...">
  <datalist id="browsers">
            <option value="Firefox" tabindex="1">
                Firefox
            </option>
            <option value="Internet" tabindex="2">
                Internet
            </option>
            <option value="Chrome" tabindex="3">
                Chrome
            </option>
            <option value="Safari" tabindex="4">
                Safari
            </option>
  </datalist>
  <button type="submit">Push me</button>
</form>
```